# Implicit function evaluation is tuned off by user?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, sandbox-solution

When I am trying to debug the `ItemUpdating` code in visual studio. I cannot see values of list values.

How can I enable this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question is off-topic in SharePoint context.

To answer, these properties cause `Side Effects` and hence its not evaluated by design. A side effect occurs when evaluating an expression changes the value of data in your application. Side effects are something to watch for if you are evaluating expressions in the debugger.

If you evaluate an expression in the Watch window or the QuickWatch dialog box and the expression has side effects, you might change the value of variables in another part of your program without realizing it. Side effects can make debugging more difficult by creating the appearance of bugs where none exist or masking the appearance of real bugs.

One common cause of side effects is evaluating a function call in a debugger window. Such evaluations are usually noticeable. A more subtle cause of side effects is the evaluation of properties and other implicit function calls in managed code.

The debugger cannot tell whether a property evaluation or implicit function call has side effects. Therefore, by default, the debugger does not evaluate implicit function calls automatically.

**When a function call or property has not been evaluated, a refresh icon appears. You can manually evaluate the expression by clicking the refresh icon.**

**[To turn automatic property evaluation on or off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ecfxd9.aspx)**

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, open the Debugging node, and click General.
3. If the Debugging node does not appear, click Show all settings.
4. Select or clear the Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls check box, and then click OK.

Comment: Can you include source link for your answer?